# how to get alphabets assigned to numeric values used a bitmask

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to assign the sequence of alphabets to the bitmask numeric values like this

```
 1: a
 2: b
 4: c
 8: d
 .....
 2^25: z
```

I am looking for a function which would help me deduce the conversion, when i select c and d , it should return me a number which is 12. i.e 4+ 8.

I wrote a function which deduces the letter from the value though, but i need the reverse now, any help  on this ? I am not very sure on teh bit wise operations

For eg,

```
var Mask = 5;
var String = "";
var index;
for (index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
    if (Mask & (1 << index)) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + index); 
        String += driveLetter;
    }
}
alert(String);
```

Comment: If I understand you right, it's impossible to reverse. because, for instance, value 16 can correspond to either "dd", or "e".

Comment: @algor The logic behind bitmasks is that you can't have two of the same flag, so the reverse operation IS possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprisingly simple:

```
var mask = 0;
var string = "cd";
for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    var c = string.charCodeAt(i) - 65;
    if (i < 0 || i >= 26) throw new SyntaxError("invalid character: "+string[i]);
    mask = mask | (1 << c); // 12
}
console.log(mask);
```